# GoogleJsonResponseException in Google people/me API

Tags: android, google-api, google-oauth, google-people-api

I am able to consume the Google `people/me` API in debug build variant using a different OAuth Client Id. But in release build type the API gives 400 Bad Request (using the release OAuth Client Id). I am sure that this has nothing to do with the OAuth Client Ids, else the OAuth would have failed. Following is the error log:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
    {
      "code" : 400,
      "message" : "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"WP\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'WP' could not be found in request message.",
      "errors" : [ {
        "message" : "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"WP\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'WP' could not be found in request message.",
        "domain" : "global",
        "reason" : "badRequest"
      } ],
      "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
```

People API Request: Here the *params* are of type `android.accounts.Account`

```
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                        MyActivity.this,
                        Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"));
                credential.setSelectedAccount(params[0]);


PeopleService service = new PeopleService.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
             .setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name))
             .build();

ListConnectionsResponse connectionsResponse = service
    .people()
    .connections()
    .list("people/me")
    .setPersonFields("names,emailAddresses")
    .execute();

return connectionsResponse.getConnections();
```